# Change the text of install folder page in NSIS

Tags: installation, directory, nsis

I need to change the text on the "Choose Install Location" page of an NSIS installer to say that my program can not be installed in a directory containing spaces in the name.

What is the best way to change this text?

Comment: All the defines required to change the text are documented in the MUI readme...

Comment: For reference: In the NSIS help file -> Appendix A -> Section 3 "Pages" -> Page settings -> Directory page settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT Foo
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT Bar
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP Baz
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_DESTINATION Bob
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
```

You might also want to check the path when the user is about to leave the page (In the page leave callback)...