# How to change the Directory Destination folder text using NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I customized the directory destination folder text using the below code snippet in English.nsh file

```
!define MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_TITLE "Destination Folder"
!define MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_SUBTITLE "Click Install to install to the default folder or click Browse to choose another"
```

But I need to change the highlighted text that is showing as "Destination Folder" to "Install EMR to:"

Here the title should be as it is like how it is showing ("Destination Folder")

How to set the highlighted text (Destination Folder) to different text ("Install EMR to:")?

I followed the below link to fix the issue but even with that also i am getting the "Destination Folder" text two times.

[Change the text of install folder page in NSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204138/change-the-text-of-install-folder-page-in-nsis)

**Below is my complete code:**

CustomEngilish.nsh

```
    !define MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_TITLE "Destination Folder"
    !define MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_SUBTITLE "Click Install to install to the default folder or click Browse to choose another"
    !define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "Install EMR to:"    
    !define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_DESTINATION "Install EMR to:"

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```

Mysetup.nsi

```
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW MyDirectoryShowCallback  
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!include "CustomEnglish.nsh"

    Function MyDirectoryShowCallback
    StrCpy $PageId 3
    SendMessage $mui.DirectoryPage.Text ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_TITLE)"
    SendMessage $mui.DirectoryPage.Text ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_SUBTITLE)"
    SendMessage $mui.DirectoryPage.Text ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP)"
    SendMessage $mui.DirectoryPage.Text ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_DESTINATION)"
    
    FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Could you show more code, please? When do you define ``!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY``?

Comment: And why don't you define ``!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "Install EMR to:"``?

Comment: How do you include the ``CustomEnglish.nsh`` file?

Comment: Are you getting compiler warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MUI_TEXT_DIRECTORY_TITLE` is the text in the top header, you want `MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP` and it needs to point to a custom language string when using multiple languages:

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP $(mydirtoptext)
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

; CustomSwedish.nsh:
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Swedish"
LangString mydirtoptext ${LANG_SWEDISH} "Swedish bork bork"

; CustomEnglish.nsh:
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
LangString mydirtoptext ${LANG_ENGLISH} "English blah blah"
```

In your screenshot the top area is gray but it should normally be white, this often indicates a problem with the order of your MUI_PAGE and MUI_LANGUAGE macros. All languages must come after the pages.